# How do you locate a specific widget when debugging in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

Newbie question here, how do you locate a specific widget in flutter? Like in android studio, you can just double click the item in the preview then it will automatically jump into the code.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect widgets bt using the Flutter Inspector in Android Studio
Just click View-> Tool Windows -> Flutter Inspector

[Read here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector) to find out more.

Comment: Note: you need the Flutter plugin for this to work.